# How to compile yocto rootfs after changing a qt.cpp file?

Tags: qt5, yocto, screen-rotation, rootfs

I want to compile a qt5 application that has replaced a previous one (both `.cpp` and `.h` file have been modified to incorporate screen rotation).

However, the rootfs doesn't seem to update when I build it, should I modify the `.bb` file?

I have simply run the build command for compiling rootfs in yocto that is

```
bitbake fsl-image-qt5-validation-imx
```

but I get a result that

```
"NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 5751 tasks of which 5751 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded."
```

This is my `.bb` file:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Freescale Image - Adds Qt5"
LICENSE = "MIT"

require recipes-fsl/images/fsl-image-validation-imx.bb

inherit distro_features_check


CONFLICT_DISTRO_FEATURES = "directfb"

# Install Freescale QT demo applications
QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL_APPS = ""
QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL_APPS_imxgpu3d = "${@bb.utils.contains("MACHINE_GSTREAMER_1_0_PLUGIN", "imx-gst1.0-plugin", "imx-qtapplications", "", d)}"

# Install fonts
QT5_FONTS = "ttf-dejavu-common ttf-dejavu-sans ttf-dejavu-sans-mono ttf-dejavu-serif "

# Install Freescale QT demo applications for X11 backend only
MACHINE_QT5_MULTIMEDIA_APPS = ""
QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL = ""
QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL_common = " \
    packagegroup-qt5-demos \
    ${QT5_FONTS} \
    ${QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL_APPS} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'x11', 'libxkbcommon', '', d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'wayland', 'qtwayland qtwayland-plugins', '', d)}\
    "
#bb file  
QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL_imxgpu2d = "${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'x11','${QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL_common}', \
    'qtbase qtbase-plugins', d)}"
#bb file 
QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL_imxpxp = "${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'x11','${QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL_common}', \
    'qtbase qtbase-examples qtbase-plugins', d)}"
#bb file 
QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL_imxgpu3d = " \
    ${QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL_common} \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-qt"

# Add packagegroup-qt5-webengine to QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL_mx6 and comment out the line below to install qtwebengine to the rootfs.
QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = " packagegroup-qt5-webengine"
#bb file 
IMAGE_INSTALL += " \
${QT5_IMAGE_INSTALL} \
    packagegroup-qt5-demos \
    wifi-bt-fw \
    ${QT5_FONTS} \
```

I expect the qt5 application to update into the rootfs, but don't know where to modify in `.bb` file.

Comment: how the app is built? where is the recipe for it?

Comment: The recipe is in folder: ~/yocto_4_9_88_qt/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-sdk/recipes-fsl/images that is where the bitbake file is located, I don't know how to build this application and have it reflect in rootfs

Comment: Also this is where i added the qt application ~/yocto_4_9_88_qt/build-fb/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.4+gitAUTOINC+0d9208cecb-r0/git/src/plugins/platforms/linuxfb

Comment: show the recipe

Comment: Would you happen to know how I can clean a qt recipe? I'd like to do that before compiling, maybe that would solve the issue